# Mx grid - very strange layout

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

[image]I work with flex 4.6 and I try to use mx:grid component to display component on my Air window.
The goal is to align some component and to have a good resizing effect.
See below code example and screenshot

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                   width="100%" verticalCenter="0" borderColor="#A8CB17">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Placer ici les éléments non visuels (services et objets de valeur, par exemple). -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <mx:Grid width="100%"
             paddingBottom="5" paddingTop="5" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" >
        <mx:GridRow id="cdr1" verticalAlign="middle" width="100%" >
            <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="left">
                <s:Label text="Label" fontWeight="bold" width="100%" paddingTop="5" color="#333333"/>
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
        <mx:GridRow id="cdr2" width="100%" borderVisible="true" dropShadowVisible="false"
                    verticalAlign="middle">
            <mx:GridItem width="100%" colSpan="1" horizontalAlign="right" verticalAlign="middle">
                <s:Label width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" text="Label1" textAlign="right"/>
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="left">
                <s:HGroup width="100%">
                    <s:CheckBox id="cbMolC1" label="Cb I" width="33%"/>
                    <s:CheckBox id="cbMolC2" label="cb. II" width="33%"/>
                    <s:CheckBox id="cbMolC3" label="Cb III" width="33%"/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem colSpan="4" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="left">
                <s:TextInput id="tiClassMol" width="100%"/>
            </mx:GridItem>

        </mx:GridRow>

        <mx:GridRow id="cdr3" verticalAlign="middle" width="100%" >
            <mx:GridItem colSpan="1" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                <s:Label width="100%" horizontalCenter="0" text="Label 2" textAlign="right"/>
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem colSpan="2" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">
                <s:HGroup width="100%">
                    <s:CheckBox id="cbMolC1" label="Cb I" width="33%"/>
                    <s:CheckBox id="cbMolC2" label="Cb II" width="33%"/>
                    <s:CheckBox id="cbMolC3" label="Cb III" width="33%"/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem colSpan="4" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="left">
                <s:TextInput id="tiClassMol" width="100%"/>
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
    </mx:Grid>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

My problem is that, even if textinput is place on a grid item whom colspan = 4, the size of this grid item is the same that the first grid item whom colspan =1.

So, I think that is very strange.

Could you help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using mx:Grid when you're using Flex 4?!

If you want a form, I definitely recommend you use the [Spark Form layout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e973827a8e912ac2b325a4-8000.html) instead of Grid, which is deprecated.

Comment: Because I have some very complex form. So grid is easier to do that.

Comment: Trust me, it isn't.  Form is much better in Spark and you can change the layout exactly as you want it.

Comment: I try and I think grid is better!

Comment: And yet you're still having problems with Grid.  Meh, whatever.  I tried.